# The variance of linear regression estimator $\beta_1$

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

Can we say

$$\text{Var}(\beta_1) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)y_i}{\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2}\right) = \left(\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)}{\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2}\right)^2 \text{Var}(y_i) \;\;??$$

I am not sure if I can separate the $x$'s i from $\sum (x_i-\bar x)y_i$. This expression seems like a linear combination of $y_i$'s. Is this legit because every $y_i$ follows the same distribution?

Comment: I've used LATEX to give your question mathematical formatting. Please double-check if it stills says what you intended.

Comment: Thanks I was editing at the same time. Did I overwrite yours?

Comment: It appears that you have overwritten me. This is fine. The most important part is two fold (1) is the question *legible* to people who might be able to answer and (2) does the formatted text say what you want?

Comment: Don't conflate the parameter with its estimate; you'll get very confused.

Comment: Briefly: *not quite*. It's not quite an identical Q but answers [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/expected-value-and-variance-of-estimation-of-slope-parameter-beta-1-in-simple) may be of some assistance.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be simple linear regression. If the $x_i$'s are treated as deterministic, then things like "variance" are not associated with them, and so the expression holds, under the additional assumption that the the error term (and hence $y$ also) has identical distribution for all $i$, and also, that the error terms (and hence $y$ also) are independent for all $j\neq i$.

For compactness, denote 
$$z_i = \frac{x_i-\bar x}{\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2}$$

Then

$$\text{Var}(\beta_1) = \text{Var}\left(\sum z_iy_i\right)$$

The assumption of deterministic $x$'s permits us to treat them as constants. The assumption of independence permits us to set the covariances between $y_i$ and $y_j$ equal to zero. These two give

$$\text{Var}(\beta_1) = \sum z_i^2\text{Var}(y_i)$$

Finally, the assumption of identically distributed $y$'s implies that $\text{Var}(y_i)= \text{Var}(y_j) \;\; \forall i,j$ and so permits us to write

$$\text{Var}(\beta_1) = \text{Var}(y_i)\sum z_i^2$$

Answer (score 3):

There are a few way to approach this. Alecos' method is simple and clear. Here's another:

$\hat{\beta}_1=\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)y_i}{\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2}=\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)y_i}{S_{xx}}=\frac{\sum d_iy_i}{S_{xx}}$

$\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_1) = \text{Var}\left(\frac{\sum (x_i-\bar x)y_i}{\sum (x_i- \bar x)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{S_{xx}^2}\text{Var}\left(\sum d_iy_i\right)=\frac{1}{S_{xx}^2}(\sum d_i^2)\text{Var}\left(y_i\right)$

You can then inspect $\sum d_i^2$ in order to do some cancelling out in the formula, and you can substitute a value for the variance of the observations.

Compare with the sample estimate of the standard error, $s_{\hat\beta}$ [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption), which should be similar up to the two obvious differences.