# Variance of slope

Tags: r, regression, variance, regression-coefficients

I have a bunch of data that I fit a linear regression to, and now I need to find the variance of my slope. Is there an analytical way to get this?

If an example is necessary, consider this my data in R:

```
x <- c(1:6)
y <- c(18, 14, 15, 12, 7, 6)
lm(y ~ x)$coefficients
```

So I have a slope estimate of `-2.4`, but I want to know the variance of that estimate.

After looking at previous questions, I've seen a few equations for estimating the slope parameter, but I'm a little confused about what the differences between equations are and what approach is valid for my problem.

For example, the answers in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122406/the-variance-of-linear-regression-estimator-beta-1) say that $\newcommand{\Var}{\rm Var}\newcommand{\slope}{\rm slope}\Var[\slope] = \frac{V[Y]}{\sum\left(\frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\right)}$.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/expected-value-and-variance-of-estimation-of-slope-parameter-beta-1-in-simple) says that $\Var[\slope] = \frac{V[Y]}{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}$.

And if I look at the output in R (as a "check" mechanism), I'm given two other ways I could potentially calculate the slope variance (one using the standard error, another given the covariance matrix). I feel like I'm missing something key because all these estimates give me similar (but not the same) answer.

Comment: Are you wondering how to get R to give this to you? (You would use [?vcov](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/vcov.html)`(model)`.) Or are you wondering where that comes from / why?

Comment: I'm less interested in R tricks, and more interested in how I would calculate the variance myself (but using R as a calculator of sorts). Does that make sense? I want to know *how* to find the variance of a slope, what formula makes sense, and not so much how can I find the answer using R.

Comment: I think the answer you want may be at the linked thread. Please read it. If it isn't what you're want / you still have a question afterwords, come back here & edit your Q to state what you learned & what you still need to know. Then we can provide the information you need w/o just duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Answer (score 5):

For a standard linear regression that meets the normal assumptions, the variances of your parameter estimates can be taken from the variance covariance matrix, $\Sigma$.  For example, the variance of the intercept is the first element on the main diagonal, $\Sigma_{11}$.  The variance of the slope on $X_1$ is the second element on the main diagonal, $\Sigma_{22}$, and so on.

There are probably many ways to skin a cat, but the standard calculation for the variance covariance matrix uses the residual variance from your model and your design matrix.  Then it is:
$$
\rm{VCov(model)} = s^2(X' X)^{-1}
$$
Here's a worked example of the calculations with your data and R:

```
x = c(1:6);    y = c(18, 14, 15, 12, 7, 6);    m = lm(y ~ x)
summary(m)
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  20.4000     1.4119   14.45 0.000133 ***
# x            -2.4000     0.3625   -6.62 0.002700 ** 
# 
# Residual standard error: 1.517 on 4 degrees of freedom
s = summary(m)$sigma;  s  # [1] 1.516575
dm = model.matrix(m);  dm
#   (Intercept) x
# 1           1 1
# 2           1 2
# 3           1 3
# 4           1 4
# 5           1 5
# 6           1 6
s^2*solve(t(dm)%*%dm)
#             (Intercept)          x
# (Intercept)    1.993333 -0.4600000
# x             -0.460000  0.1314286
vcov(m)  # you can see that this is the same as the manual calculation above
#             (Intercept)          x
# (Intercept)    1.993333 -0.4600000
# x             -0.460000  0.1314286
sqrt(diag(vcov(m)))  # these are the same standard errors as the summary output
# (Intercept)           x 
#   1.4118546   0.3625308
```

Comment: I follow that, and I understand and agree that that's how you would manually get the variance/covariance matrix, but I still don't understand the equations in those other questions. The method in your answer gives one result, but those two equations give a different one. Is there some scaling factor the variance covariance matrix doesn't take into account?

Comment: @user72320, you can see that both the variance covariance matrix & the manual calculation give exactly the right answer. It the equations from the other Qs differ, they are wrong. Note also that Glen_b's answer below gives the proof for the formula used here.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do this for the multiple regression case:
\begin{align}
\text{Var}((X'X)^{-1}X'y) &= (X'X)^{-1}X'\text{Var}(y)X'(X'X)^{-1}  \\
                          &=(X'X)^{-1}X'(\sigma^2I)X'(X'X)^{-1}  \\
                          &=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}X'X'(X'X)^{-1}  \\
                          &=\sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}
\end{align}
which is usually estimated by $s^2(X'X)^{-1}$