# Expected value of the parameters in linear regression (trying to understand which part is constant and which isn't and why)

Tags: regression, expected-value, estimators

I'm studying Linear Regression and trying to proof/demonstrate some properties of the parameters. When I started working with the expected value of the slope, I got confused with something. I actually couldn't reach the expected result, which is beta 1.

So, I found a demonstration very close to what I was doing and I was hoping someone could explain to me the part where I got stuck. First, we have beta 1 parameter:

[image]

The author then uses Ci to make his demonstration less messy:

[image]

The following step is where I got confused. When I see the next part of the demonstration (see picture below), I have no idea why is Ci constant, but Yi isn't! Why is the expected value of Ci equal to Ci, but Yi isn't Yi?

[image]

(I even tried this link [Expected Value and Variance of Estimation of Slope Parameter $\beta_1$ in Simple Linear Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/expected-value-and-variance-of-estimation-of-slope-parameter-beta-1-in-simple), but I got nothing. And even in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rODUBTRUV0U, the author doesn't explain why is Ci a constant, he just assumes)

Comment: You are correct: one *assumes* the $x_i$ are given--that is, are constant.  Since the $C_i$ are functions of the $x_i,$ the $C_i$ are also constant.